# How to specify ReadOnly query in C# using SqlCommand()

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlcommand

I'm using C# with .NET `SqlDataReader()`, `SqlConnection()`, `SqlCommand()` and `.ExecuteReader()` classes.

In vbScript, I can open RecordSets like this:

```
rs.open cSQL, cn, adOpenForwardonly, adLockReadonly
```

The `rs.open` statement can be given arguments to make the query ForwardOnly, and ReadOnly.

How do I do the same thing with C# and its `SqlCommand()` class?

Comment: You cannot really do this with `SqlCommand` - the question whether the current user can edit something or not depends on the **permissions** in the SQL Server database - not the access technology (ADO.NET, Entity Framework etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In ADO.NET you handle it differently from the old days with cursors which you had to specify as forward only etc. The method you are looking for is called `ExecuteReader`. Consider the following code...

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryString, connection);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

This then gets you a `SqlDataReader` that contains your values and is essentially a forward only, read only structure.

Comment: Oops.  I am using the .ExecuteReader() method.  Forgot to include that in the original post.  I edited and added it.  Thanks.